# Delay pipe execution after getting data

Tags: angular

Hi Below is my drop down, which has custom pipe included, but the problem I face is that data for that particular variable is received from api which takes sometime. Before that pipe gets executed with empty data.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="floating-label">
    <select class="floating-select" value="" formControlName="curreny" id="user">
      <option *ngFor="let val of trCurrency | keyValue" [ngValue]="val.key">{{val.value}}</option>
    </select>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <label>Currency</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting trCurrency  value a bit later, is there a way to change order of execution or can I add other conditions to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT :

Ok then you do not need `async` pipe. A small `*ngIf` should satisfy your requirement.

```
<div class="floating-label" *ngIf= "trCurrency">
    <select class="floating-select" value="" formControlName="curreny" id="user">
      <option *ngFor="let val of trCurrency | keyValue" [ngValue]="val.key">{{val.value}}</option>
    </select>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <label>Currency</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: I`m getting this error InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: That is probably not an observable then. So why it is making a delay to load the data? Can you show how you are setting `trCurrency`.

Comment: this.apiService.getFileContent("data.json").subscribe(
            success => {
                console.log(success);
                this.currency = success['trCurrency'];                
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        )

Comment: The above getting response from api

Comment: `this.currency` and `trCurrency`, are they two different array variables?

Comment: Sorry I have changed variable name recently this is the html
 <option *ngFor="let val of (currency|async) | keyValue" [ngValue]="val.key">{{val.value}}</option>

Comment: Ok then you do not need `async` pipe. A small `*ngIf` should satisfy your requirement. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead I have added ngif to check whether the value is present or not.

```
    <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf ="currency != ''">
      <div class="floating-label">
        <select class="floating-select" value="" formControlName="currency" id="user">
          <option *ngFor="let val of (currency) | keyValue" [ngValue]="val.key">{{val.value}}</option>
        </select>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <label>Currency</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```